# How to add a description for a method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have in one script this method :

```
public void StartFade(bool isIn, bool autoSwitch)
    {
        if (canvasGroup != null)
        {
            if (_currentRoutine != null)
            {
                if (_currentDirection != isIn)
                {
                    StopCoroutine(_currentRoutine);

                    _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(Fade(canvasGroup, isIn, autoSwitch));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(Fade(canvasGroup, isIn, autoSwitch));
            }
        }
    }
```

then i'm calling this method in many other scripts like :

```
public void HoverOut()
    {
        fader.StartFade(false, false);
    }
```

when i type StartFade(

at this point i want to see some description of what the StartFade method do.
now i only see :

[image: method]

Comment: i still can't solve and figure out why when i type ( for example StartFade( i see old comment ? look at this image screenshot please : imgur.com/a/YbXKDcI you can see that when i type ( it's showing some fsdfdf.... this was the first time i used the /// summary for some reason it's remembering and showing this old first comment and not showing the new text in the comments like in your answer. it's showing the comments in your answer if i put the mouse cursor over the method name StartFade but if i type StartFade( with the ( symbol then it's showing something else this fsdfdf....

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for are XML Documentation Comments. The Microsoft Docs for them are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/)

They allow you to comment on the method, and most IDE's will pick those comments up in their suggestion/autocompletion.

In this example, it would be something like:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Your summary
/// </summary>
public void StartFade(bool isIn, bool autoSwitch)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Working great.  i tried to write some description and i can see the first line but then i added few more lines and can't see them why is that ? I did : /// <summary> then here some text then i pressed enter // and here entered more text then // and some more text and in the end /// </summary> but i see only the first line.

Comment: Youd should use tiple-slash for all lines of the doc comment if you're using single line style, or, if you want to use multiline style, use `/** */` and precede each new line with *.
The specific comment style docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/#xml-comment-formats

Comment: i found something strange.  first time i used /// <summary> // some text here /// </summary> then when i tried to change the line text or even changed the whole format with br tag and para and other text i still see the old first text line i used the first time.  it's not showing the new text and changes i did. it's like remembering the first thing i did first.  i tried to rebuild.

Comment: That sounds like an IDE issue unfortunately.

Comment: first i tried with visual studio community 2019 now i switched to visual studio 2022 community and still the same problem.  strange.

Comment: i found that if you put the mouse on the StartFade it will show the new comment but if you make StartFade( it's showing the first old comment.  not sure why.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi have you clicked into Unity to recompile the scripts? IDE might not update until your code is compiled into the solution

Comment: @derHugo i compiled the scripts in vs 2019 and 2022 same result. when you move the mouse cursor over the method name StartFade you see the new updated comment/s but when you make StartFade( you see the old first comment even if the comment is not exist in the code.  i found for now at least one file on the hard disk that saved the old comment it's not xml file tried to deleted it but it didn't change much so i'm looking for other files that contain it but it's still unclear.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi One thing it could be worth trying is doing a clean, or deleting the .vs folder to try and remove any cached assets that could contain the original documentation. I tried to recreate what you're seeing and I couldn't. Last option might be to remove the comment, rebuild and re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Description...
/// <para>New line description for method...</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="isIn">isIn description...</param>
/// <param name="autoSwitch">
/// autoSwitch description...
/// <para>New line description for autoSwitch parameter...</para>
/// </param>
/// <returns>Return description...</returns>
public void StartFade(bool isIn, bool autoSwitch)
{
}
```

[image]

Comment: i still can't solve and figure out why when i type ( for example StartFade( i see old comment ? look at this image screenshot please : https://imgur.com/a/YbXKDcI you can see that when i type ( it's showing some fsdfdf.... this was the first time i used the /// summary for some reason it's remembering and showing this old first comment and not showing the new text in the comments like in your answer.  it's showing the comments in your answer if i put the mouse cursor over the method name StartFade but if i type StartFade( with the ( symbol then it's showing something else this  fsdfdf....

Comment: where it's keeping this  fsdfdf.... comment i did long before ? why i can't change it ? if i put them ouse cursor on the function name i see the new comments like in your answer but when i type StartFade( when i type the ( symbol i see the old comment.  this is strange.